# Jquery: SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello stackovlerflow,

```
function delete() {
    if ($.('#deleted').value=="0") {
        $.("#deleted").val('1');
        $.("#deletedBtn").removeClass('btn-danger');
        $.("#deletedBtn").addClass('btn-success');
        $.("#deletedBtn").html("Delete user");
    } else {
        $.("#deleted").val('0');
        $.("#deletedBtn").removeClass('btn-success');
        $.("#deletedBtn").addClass('btn-danger');
        $.("#deletedBtn").html("Revoke deletion");
    }
}
```

Tis function throws me

> SyntaxError: function statement requires a name functions.js:1:9

Google doesn`t help, so I hope you can help me!

Thanks alot
//Cripi

Comment: Better use the different function name `del()` instead of `delete()` . Because delete is the reserved of javascript

Comment: Change your function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*delete* is a reserved word in JavaScript - see [List of reserved words in JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Your code could look like this:

```
function fun() {
    var deleted = $("#deleted");
    var deletedBtn = $("#deletedBtn");

    if (deleted.val() === "0") {
        deleted.val('1');
        deletedBtn.removeClass('btn-danger');
        deletedBtn.addClass('btn-success');
        deletedBtn.html("Delete user");
    } else {
        deleted.val('0');
        deletedBtn.removeClass('btn-success');
        deletedBtn.addClass('btn-danger');
        deletedBtn.html("Revoke deletion");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, now i get `SyntaxError: missing name after . operator`

Comment: Please use $('#deleted') instead of $.('#deleted')

Comment: I still get `SyntaxError: missing name after . operator  functions.js:2:10`
Line in in functions.js is `$("#deletedBtn").addClass('btn-danger');`

Comment: This line looks fine. Try to change $('#deleted').value to $('#deleted').val()

Comment: It doesn't helps :|

Comment: I've updated the answer. This code should works just fine as it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use delete as a method name since it is reserved in javascript.

Also you might want to use a variable to avoid duplication in your code:

```
function deleteAction() {
    $btn = $('#deleted');
    if ($btn.value=="0") {
        $btn.val('1');
        $btn.html("Delete user");
    } else {
        $btn.val('0');
        $btn.html("Revoke deletion");
    }
    $btn.toggleClass("btn-danger btn-success");
}
```